Is there any way to wait curl response not more than a certain time, but get response later in a PHP application?
My application uses curl for getting remote data. I want to optimize the application response timeout. My point is:

send curl request
wait it only 0.5 seconds
if curl responses faster I cache it, send data to output and do exit()
but if it slower than 0.5 seconds I want to curl continues this request but I make ob_end_flush() to close client connection and then wait curl response until it done to cache it.

It would be nice to implement it with the symfony/http-client.

Thinking out loud here, but it might be easier and cleaner to just treat all of the requests the same, regardless of their timing.  Have the web app just store any data needed and immediately return control to the UI.  Then have a separate background process which responds to that data and makes the requests, updating the data with the results.  The web app can respond to the updated data.  (Maybe there's a page showing the results that needs to be refreshed, maybe there's a web socket which notifies the user, maybe something else, etc.)

David is right - just hand the curl work off to a backend process. Your idea fundamentally falls down I think because the curl request is synchronous - while it's running, all of your other code is waiting for the curl request to return. You haven't got anything independent which can time 0.5 seconds and run ob_end_flush while the curl request is ongoing.

@David and ADyson are right the simplest implementation of their suggestion I use is to send signup email using phpmailer lib. I don't run mail sending directly from script but save it in db as cron and simply kick the cron from the script using exec to run the cron which actually sends out the mail. This return the call/control immediately to user without waiting.
Recently modified for downloading large amount of data from and API and it work great in the background.
